# Question about Stm32 "Blue Pill" NRST pin schematic

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, circuit-design, schematics, reset

I have a question about the schematic design of the STM32 "Blue Pill" board. In the datasheet it says there is an internal pull-up resistor of ~40k is included in the MCU for the NRST pin connection ([datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103c8.pdf)):

[image]

[image]

But in the schematic design of the STM32 "Blue Pill" there is included a 10k pull-up resistor externally:
[image]

Wouldn't this make the equivalent parallel resistance to be 10k//40k = 8k and therefore increase the pull-up current and reduce the efficiency of the NRST pin. Making the pull-up resistor smaller would make it a stronger pull-up but in this case I don't see it necessary since the NRST connection would be short and near the MCU anyway. Is there a reason behind this decision that I am unaware of?

Comment: Notice that **NRST** is brought to a header pin, which means that a user has access. **Who knows what a user might tie in?** Perhaps the designer decided to strengthen pull-up to mitigate externally-brought-in noise on this line. Not much worse than a randomly-resetting microcontroller.

Comment: @glen_geek That is exactly the reason a product like that must have a manual. The pin already has a 100nF capacitor for reset timing, so it has fairly low AC impedance to begin with, not very prone to pick up noise. Plus it is an open-drain IO pin, which the user should know too in order to keep the MCU and connected thing operational without damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, nRST has internal pull-up already. It does not need an external pull-up. Adding an external pull-up in addition to the internal will charge up the capacitor faster as per your calculations.

External pull-up is not mentioned or suggested. A long time ago STM32 datasheets mentioned that an external pull-up could be used in an environment with lots of electromagnetic interference. But it has been removed.

Why the pull-up is there is unknown. Some other MCUs don't have internal pull-ups on their reset pins, so it is a reasonable assumption to have a pull-up on reset pin.

That is not the only thing wrong or against datasheet suggestions in the Blue Pill, so take it as an example how not to make a product by ignoring datasheets, hardware getting started guides, and application notes of the MCU manufacturer.

Comment: Yes, I figured out many other problems along the way, like some cap values and placements, etc., but I want to ask another question about the datasheet. the first picture (Table 38. NRST pin characteristics) uses the adjective "Weak" about the internal pull-up resistor. What exactly is meant by that?

Comment: @Berk Everything is relative, but since the internal resistance is about 40 kilo-ohms, it is not very strong in the context.